# MongoDB bson_date_t to local time

Tags: c++, mongodb

I appended date to the mongodb like this

```
bson_append_date(b,"uploadDate",(bson_date_t)1000*time(NULL));
```

Do remember that this will append "milliseconds since epoch UTC" and saved as `2014-06-27 06:11:56`

Now i am reading it out and it is giving milliseconds (`1403852029`) which is exactly right. Now i want to convert it into local time. I tried to use the localtime function of C++ but did get success as the time returned by mongodb is in int64_t.

```
if(bson_iterator_type(&it)==BSON_DATE)
bson_date_t date_it = bson_iterator_date( &it );
```

where bson_date_t is `typedef int64_t bson_date_t;`. Can anyone tell me how i can get the local time from the milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting a valid time_t that would work with localtime should be exactly the opposite of what you are doing in the forward conversion:

```
bson_append_date(b,"uploadDate",(bson_date_t)1000*time(NULL));
```

To have a workable time_t, you should do following:

```
time_t rawTime = (time_t)(bson_iterator_date( &it ) / 1000);
struct tm * timeinfo = localtime (&rawTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

One more method.

```
bson_date_t date_it = bson_iterator_date( &it );
struct tm* ts;
time_t epoch_time_as_time_t= date_it/1000;
ts=localtime(&epoch_time_as_time_t);
strftime(upload_Date,sizeof(upload_date),"%a %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z",ts);
```